# How to create an new independent (not alias) list to a old list while using repeat - AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I want to pick certain elements in a oldList, and then create a new one, like the following

Example#1: Get odd number
oldList = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
newList = {1,3,5,7}

Example#2: Get string
oldList = {1,"Tiger",{1,2,3}
newList = {"Tiger"}

I write a script for the example 1:

```
set oldList to {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}  

set newList to {}  
repeat with theItem in oldList  
    if theItem mod 2 = 1 then  
        copy theItem to end of newList  
    end if  
end repeat
```

I expect the newList should be {1,3,5} but actually it's {item 1 of oldList,item 2 of oldList,,item 3 of oldList}. My question is how to solve this problem.

As for this specific example, a simple solution is change the **copy statement** into something like:

```
copy theItem as integer to end of newList
```

But I am looking for a more general solution, instead tedious consider the class of the element in the old list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should read more about [how repeat loops work in AppleScript.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-127362)

```
set oldList to {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

set newList to {}
repeat with theItem in oldList
    set theItem to contents of theItem
    if theItem mod 2 = 1 then
        copy theItem to end of newList
    end if
end repeat
```